# Tomcat 7.0.42 Manager Weird behavior

Tags: linux, virtualhost, java, tomcat7

Good morning folks!

I'm playing with my brand new tomcat installation today, and everything run pretty smoothly except that I got a weird reaction using the manager with virtualhosts.

The problem pop out when I try to deploy a webapp on my vhost A1 It's quite working, upload works but not the start of the app.

When I try to deploy another webapp on vhost A2 is not working at all, I can't even upload the archive.

The weird thing is both virtualhosts use the same manager.xml configuration file hosted under ${Catalina.base}/conf/Catalina/[engine]/[hostname]/manager.XML

This file is calling my main manager and this same manager is working perfectly.

When I said that the manager crash weirdly on my vhosts it's because it return a 503 error message which ask me to set the tomcat user roles and password on the tomcat-users.xml but the point is that this file is already set on the default file provided by tomcat.

If I upload my apps directly on the host appbase / docbase directory it's working perfectly due to the AutoDeploy and DeployOnStartup directives on the server.xml config file.

So if anyone of you have a hint, I'll take it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solve my problem by myself, I'll then explain it:

Tomcat manager and default applications are CSRF protected.
Since I'm using VHosts behind a reverse-proxy which is relaying the client IP/domain informations, tomcat found something too weird for him and then throw a 403 response.

Solution: do not relay Origin IP/domain.